# opencv4tegra: issues compiling sample stereo_match.cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, nvidia, tegra

I am having considerable difficulty compiling a standard opencv sample with opencv4tegra - installed as instructed by the nvidia wiki for the Jetson TK1.

Out of frustration I built opencv from the 2.4.10.1 source and I installed it directly into /usr/local... and it worked great! After I uninstalled it I had the same issue compiling against theirs, so clearly it is something that I am doing. Funny thing is, I can run the compiled sample app against their opencv4tegra lib just fine... but I cannot compile against their lib.

Test environment:

I did not change the sample file from 2.4.10.1 release of opencv - it is the same stereo_match.cpp file. I'm just trying to compile it.

The functions are inside the gpu.hpp file - I have already looked. I have also run:

`nm /usr/lib/libopencv_gpu.so | grep StereoBM_GPU | c++filt`

...just to ensure the symbols are in the library.

What is going on?? So, it's clearly not linking - but I can't figure out what g++ wants...

> $:~/opencv/samples/gpu$ `` g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib
>   `pkg-config opencv --libs` stereo_match.cpp -o stereo_m ``
>
> /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In function `App::App(Params const&)':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x8b0): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::StereoBM_GPU::StereoBM_GPU()'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x8c6): undefined reference to
>   `cv::gpu::StereoBeliefPropagation::StereoBeliefPropagation(int, int,
>   int, int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x8e0): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::StereoConstantSpaceBP::StereoConstantSpaceBP(int, int, int,
>   int, int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x8e4): undefined reference to
>   `cv::gpu::getDevice()' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x8ec): undefined
>   reference to`cv::gpu::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(int)' /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o:
>   In function `App::run()': stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xa42): undefined
>   reference to`cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xa70): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xb90):
>   undefined reference to`cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xba0): undefined reference to
>   `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xbb4): undefined reference to`
>   cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int,
>   int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xbc4): undefined reference to
>   `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xbd4): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xbe8): undefined reference to
>   `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int,
>   int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xbfa): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xc0c): undefined reference to
>   `cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xc3e): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xc4e): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xc94): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xca4): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xdaa): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xdba): undefined reference to
>   `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xdce): undefined reference to`
>   cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int,
>   int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xdde): undefined reference to
>   `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xdee): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xe02): undefined reference to
>   `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int,
>   int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xe4e): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xe60): undefined reference to
>   `cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xe92): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xea2): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xee8): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xef8): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xf22): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::Stream::Null()' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xf34): undefined
>   reference to `cv::gpu::StereoBM_GPU::operator()(cv::gpu::GpuMat
>   const&, cv::gpu::GpuMat const&, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, cv::gpu::Stream&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xf4c): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::Stream::Null()' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xf5e): undefined
>   reference to
>   `cv::gpu::StereoBeliefPropagation::operator()(cv::gpu::GpuMat const&,
>   cv::gpu::GpuMat const&, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, cv::gpu::Stream&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xf76): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::Stream::Null()' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xf88): undefined
>   reference to
>   `cv::gpu::StereoConstantSpaceBP::operator()(cv::gpu::GpuMat const&,
>   cv::gpu::GpuMat const&, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, cv::gpu::Stream&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xfa0): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::GpuMat::download(cv::Mat&) const'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0xff6): undefined reference to
>   `cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int,
>   double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1032): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1042): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x105c): undefined reference to`
>   cv::waitKey(int)' /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In function
>   `App::handleKey(char)': stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1630): undefined
>   reference to`cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1640): undefined reference to
>   `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1654): undefined reference to`
>   cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int,
>   int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1664): undefined reference to
>   `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1674): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1688): undefined reference to
>   `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int,
>   int)' stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x169a): undefined reference to`
>   cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x16ac): undefined reference to
>   `cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1718): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x1728): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x176e): undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text+0x177e): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In function`cv::Mat::~Mat()':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x20):
>   undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)' /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In
>   function`cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text.*ZN2cv3MataSERKS0*[*ZN2cv3MataSERKS0*]+0xa2):
>   undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
>   /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In function`cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat6createEiii[_ZN2cv3Mat6createEiii]+0x66):
>   undefined reference to `cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
>   /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In function`cv::Mat::release()':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[*ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x30):
>   undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()' /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In
>   function`cv::gpu::GpuMat::GpuMat(cv::Size*, int)':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3gpu6GpuMatC2ENS_5Size_IiEEi[_ZN2cv3gpu6GpuMatC5ENS_5Size_IiEEi]+0x5c):
>   undefined reference to `cv::gpu::GpuMat::create(int, int, int)'
>   /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In function`cv::gpu::GpuMat::~GpuMat()':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3gpu6GpuMatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3gpu6GpuMatD5Ev]+0xa):
>   undefined reference to `cv::gpu::GpuMat::release()' /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o:
>   In function`App::workBegin()':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN3App9workBeginEv[_ZN3App9workBeginEv]+0x8):
>   undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()' /tmp/ccvj1IgD.o: In
>   function`App::workEnd()':
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN3App7workEndEv[_ZN3App7workEndEv]+0x8):
>   undefined reference to `cv::getTickCount()'
>   stereo_match.cpp:(.text._ZN3App7workEndEv[_ZN3App7workEndEv]+0x20):
>   undefined reference to`cv::getTickFrequency()' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you provide the libraries (`.a`) as `-l` options and the directories where to find them with the `-L` option in your linker command line?

Comment: I don't know if we're speaking the same thing? and this is not a duplicate...

So, `pkg-config opencv --libs` will return the path to all the library shared objects (.so) 

The `-L` I provided is for the `-lcudart` ect... provided by the pkg-config cmd... but to answer your question directly, adding `-L/usr/lib` additionally will not help. I've already tried it.

Comment: You are linking.  These are linker errors.  I can only assume `pkg-config` is not returning the flags to include the library that contains the definitions of those symbols.

Comment: `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has little to do here. It's an environment variable used by the _dynamic linker_ when you _attempt_ to _run_ the program. It's GCC's `-L/path/to/lib` flags that you use to tell it to find libraries in non-default paths. And for your information, those ___are___ linker errors. Don't take our word, it even says so itself in your error message: `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`, though it's conceivable that the preprocessor header GCC finds misdeclares those functions. And lastly, OpenCV4Tegra is closed-source.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I did figure out that opencv4tegra is closed source, however, thanks for readdressing this. I also did see the `ld` error, but I'm just confused as to why... When I run `ldd` on the opencv I compiled using `make` it is properly linked. I am about to give up and just use `make` in general.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I'm not sure I know what you mean? When I run `pkg-config opencv --libs` I get what is inside `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`. I did not create this file, either added by `apt` or was inside the `opencv4tegra-*.deb` package. 

Is this not correct?

`/usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so ...more... -lcufft -lnpps -lnppi -lnppc -lcudart -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl`

Comment: Think I found my issue. Thanks for the clue @IwillnotexistIdonotexist. The macros inside the opencv cmake make references to opencv_nonfree... perhaps it was sobel or something. Hence, why the entire library builds it.

Comment: @hhony If you found your own solution, you should consider self-answering your question; It's permitted, even encouraged.

Comment: I did already. It didn't seem to post for some reason. :)

Answer (score 2):

See the macros inside cmake instructions for packaging in opencv and stick to using make. Thanks again for the clue 'Iwillnotexist Idonotexist'.

In my case, there were two dependencies I missed: 
/modules/gpu/src/nvidia && /modules/gpu/src/nvidia/core
...and there were references to 'nonfree' in other parts.

Hidden dependency stuff... oh boy.

Thanks for all the contributing responses - seems trivial now.